# Lucene query for multiple fields

Tags: lucene

We are using Lucene 5.5 and based upon documentation all the operators work on a single term and then you join criteria with AND / OR etc.

Is there a way in Lucene 5.5 to query multiple terms with min/max operations?

If there are two fields, let's say `field1` and `field2` (both integers), the requirement is to have:

```
field1 != 0 and field2 != 0 and min(field1, field2) is between (0 to 100)
```

Which API class should be used to achieve the above?

Comment: I am not aware of anything like `min( field1, field2 )` when executing a query. Maybe there is, but I would instead create a new field `field3` and populate it at index time based on that. Lucene has [range searching](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_8_2/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Range_Searches) as part of the classic query parser. Lucene also has various `FooRange` classes such as [this one](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_8_2/core/org/apache/lucene/document/IntRange.html).

Comment: If none of that meets your needs, please consider [edit]ing your question to provide a [mre] and a specific issue you may be facing.